# Retrieve and displaying BLOB images from Mysql database with Tkinter

Tags: python, mysql, tkinter, blob

this def should connect to a database, and if the parameters are correct should retrieve a BLOB image, however i confused on how to display that image. currently, it will display all the other information besides the BLOB image that i want to be displayed. i realize that setting it to a stringvar is not correct. can anyone help with some clarity on how to get this to display in Tkinter? if not, is there any alternative solutions?

```
func = Tkinter.Toplevel()
func.title("blah")
func.geometry('400x400+0+0)

db = MySQLdb.connect(host='xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx', user='xxx',passwd='xxxx',db='xxxxx')
cursor = db.cursor()

FirstName = QE1.get()
LastName = QE2.get()
SSN = QE3.get()

cursor execute ("""SELECT pat_face FROM PATIENT WHERE pat_firstname=%s AND pat_lastname=%s AND pat_id=%s""",(FirstName,LastName,SSN))

PATFACEresults = StringVar()
PATFACEresults.set(cursor.fetchone())

db.close()

PATFACE = Tkinter.Label(func, textvariable=PATFACEresults).grid(row=0,column=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll need PIL for this (and possibly StringIO as well).

something like:

```
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
import cStringIO

...

results = cursor.fetchone()
data = cStringIO.StringIO(results.tostring())
pic = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(data))

patface = Tkinter.Label(func, image=pic)
patface.grid(row=0, column=1)
```

You could also try saving the image direct to a file & loading it from there.

more info:

- http://zetcode.com/databases/mysqlpythontutorial/
- http://www.effbot.org/zone/pil-index.htm
- http://www.effbot.org/tkinterbook/