# Python, Sqlite - how to put an image stored (either as Blob or base64 string) in a sqlite DB on a tkinter Label

Tags: python, sqlite, tkinter

I guess this question probably will get accused of duplication but honestly I wasn't able to find my way despite spending quite long time fumbling around here and there.

It's straightforward to store an image in a Sqlite DB as Blob but the reverse action in a way that's suitable for my intended use (which is *retrieving that image* in order to *displaying on a label*) is not. There is a not accepted guid [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8317421/retrieve-and-displaying-blob-images-from-mysql-database-with-tkinter?rq=1) that I hope someone verifies, explains and corrects it (for instance may I use *str()* instead of *tostring()* in this line?)

`data = cStringIO.StringIO(results.tostring())`

There's also a lot of talk about that an *image could be stored in DB as a base64 string*. I think it would make the retrieving and displaying process easier maybe at the expense of extra actions while storing (by the way I couldn't find any concrete guide on how to do that).

Please give some instructions in layman's term, it would be very appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following to turn it into an Image object which tkinter could then display through a label (or elsewhere) from a base64 string.

```
from PIL import Image
import base64, io
# Get the base64 string
Image.open(io.BytesIO(base64.b64decode(data)))
```

Comment: What if image has been stored as Blob type? Would  `Image.open(io.BytesIO(retrieved Blob field))` work?